# Remove background in grid view

Tags: flutter

I have a grid view which return a card. The problem is the grid view has some white color in its background. How can I remove it.[image]

Comment: Please put some code to check what have you tried, also you can check this post to improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, in that way more people can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the `GridView` with `Ink` and change the color. Check the following example

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
          body: Ink(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: GridView.count(
                primary: false,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: const Text("He'd have you all unravel at the"),
                    color: Colors.teal[100],
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: const Text('Heed not the rabble'),
                    color: Colors.teal[200],
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: const Text('Sound of screams but the'),
                    color: Colors.teal[300],
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: const Text('Who scream'),
                    color: Colors.teal[400],
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: const Text('Revolution is coming...'),
                    color: Colors.teal[500],
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: const Text('Revolution, they...'),
                    color: Colors.teal[600],
                  ),
                ],
              ))),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text('Hello, World!', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4);
  }
}
```